# How can I display the data of the current_user only? Not of all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my **index.html.erb** I display @events which is defined (in my event_controller) as

```
@events = Event.all
```

In my **application_controller** I have `@current_user` defined as

```
@current_user ||= Maker.find(session[:maker_id]) if session[:maker_id]
```

Basically I'm using *maker* instead of the usual *user*.

I realize that because `@events = Event.all` it will display *all* the events, regardless of the maker, but I was wondering, how can I display **only** the events that are ***associated* with** the current_user's maker_id?

The current problem is that a maker can see the events of another maker in Event#index.

The relationship between events and makers is:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :maker 

end
```

and

```
class Maker < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :events

end
```

Comment: in your index method inside eventscontroller use this @events = current_user.events

Comment: thanks, that seems to have worked

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like

```
@events = current_user.try(:events) || Event.all
```

So it will not give any error even if current_user is nil.

Comment: problem with this is that @events will be nil if there are no current user.  it may be the expected behavior but it can also be "show all events if there is not current user".

Comment: @jvnill is it ok now?

Comment: well it's still the OP's requirement that you have to satisfy but personally, I prefer `where` and try to stop using `try` as much as possible.

Comment: why you don't want to use try?